# How to properly return a set of instances from a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to instanciate a series of Objects, each one exposing a function, and then return them as a node.js module to be used elsewhere in my project.

I tried using this:

```
function Role(id, ext) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ext = ext || [];
}

Role.prototype.filter = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user)
        return res.status(401).send({
            "message": "unauthorized"
        });
    if (req.user.role !== this.id && this.ext.indexOf(req.user.role) < 0)
        return res.status(403).send({
            "mesage": "forbidden"
        });
    return next();
};

var Roles = {
    admin: new Role("admin"),
    member: new Role("member", ["admin"]) // admin extends member
};

module.exports = Roles;
```

Which does not work, this.id and this.ext not being defined when filter is called from any instance used in my other module.

Instead, this works:

```
var Role = function(id, ext) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = id;
    self.ext = ext || [];
    self.filter = function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.user)
            return res.status(401).send({
                "message": "unauthorized"
            });
        if (req.user.role !== self.id && self.ext.indexOf(req.user.role) < 0)
            return res.status(403).send({
                "mesage": "forbidden"
            });
        return next();
    };
}


var Roles = {
    admin: new Role("admin"),
    member: new Role("member", ["admin"]) // admin extends member
};

module.exports = Roles;
```

... but looks far more unelegant.

What's wrong with the first construct ? I'm pretty new with javascipt oop but it looks pretty similar to what I've seen reading here and there about how to define classes and instances methods with this language.

**UPDATE**

As per request and for clarification here is how function is called in my other module:

```
router.get('/', filter, Roles.admin.filter, function(req, res, next) {
    // doing some business
});
```

Comment: try `this.filter=this.filter.bind(this);` in costructor.

Comment: It works, thanks @zb', and so for that 'bind' trick

Comment: It depends upon how `.filter()` is called.  Your first one will work if `.filter()` is called correctly so you will have to show us how you are using the `Roles` object from your first code example.  In Javascript, `this` is determine by how a function is called, NOT by how it is declared.  A proper method call with set things appropriately.  Show us the calling code when you're using the first scenario.

Comment: Updated the question, as guessed in @rpadovani answer, I was using filter as an express middleware which was making function calls executing in another context, as everyone  helpfully stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`this` changes its value depending on how the function is invoked**.

`this` keyword works differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. I suggest you to read [the guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on MDN website.

In your both your cases `this` is set to the caller's scope (I suppose is a library like *restify* or *expressjs*).

You can verify that doing

```
Role.prototype.filter = function(req, res, next) {console.log(this)}
```

In the second case you use `self` to save the context of `this`. If you try to use `this` you will see the value of `this` is the same of the first example.

So your two examples work in the same way, but in the second you used `self = this` as workaround.

### Workaround

Javascript provides 3 functions to change the value of this, forcing the scope of a function: `apply()`, `call()` and `bind()`.

In your case I'm quite sure `bind()` is the best option.

Somewhere in your code, basing on what library you're using, you have something like:

```
server.get('/route', Roles.filter);
```

You need to change it to

```
server.get('route', Roles.filter.bind(Roles));
```

Now, without knowing how you call the function I'm quite sure this isn't going to work, but anyway, what you need is pass as argument of `bind()` an instance of class Roles. In this way `this` will be set to the value of that instance of Roles.

### Differences between bind(), apply() and call()

I said I think you need to use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) because it is the only one of the three functions that doesn't call the function, but just set the scope. In your case I think you're using a library to provide APIs (due the *req, res, next*), so you do not want to call the function, just having a reference to it.

[call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) instead call the function. The only difference between them is how you pass argument: `call()` accepts a list of arguments, `apply()` an array:

```
function.call(scope, arg1, arg2, arg3);
function.apply(scope, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

Comment: I'm not sure i'm getting it. I tried running the code in the console, and what I get printing {this} is an object containing id and ext, both being defined, but without any filter function attached to it. I was thinking using Role.prototype assignation was designed for this purpose. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @36ve it depends on how you call the function. If you call the `filter()` function from inside the `Role` class then this will be the object itself. If you call from out of the class (so in the same way you say it fails) you will see value of `this` will change

Comment: @36ve there is simple rule - `this` is equal to object which stay last before function name, so if you call `funct()`  `this` will be global or `null` (depends on `'use strict'` and environment) if you call `something.other.func()`, `this` will be `something other`. when binding you doing something like

Comment: `function bind() {var args = Array.from(arguments); var funct = args.shift();var context = args.shift(); return function() {var localArgs = args.concat(arguments);funct.call(context, localArgs)};}; var binded = bind(someFunct, itsContext, arg1, arg2); binded(arg3, arg4);`

Comment: Accepting this answer for the good guess and the usefull links I obviously need to dive in.

Answer (score 1):

You are loosing context of function, so you have to `bind` this context or mean it when calling

bind example:

```
function Role(id, ext) {
    this.id = id;
    this.ext = ext || [];
    // you should understand, that bind creates new function, this time it ok.
    this.filter = this.filter.bind(this); 
}

Role.prototype.filter = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.user)
        return res.status(401).send({
            "message": "unauthorized"
        });
    if (req.user.role !== this.id && this.ext.indexOf(req.user.role) < 0)
        return res.status(403).send({
            "mesage": "forbidden"
        });
    return next();
};

var Roles = {
    admin: new Role("admin"),
    member: new Role("member", ["admin"]) // admin extends member
};

module.exports = Roles;
```

"mean" examples:

use your initial code, but when calling method use `call` or `apply` or `bind`

```
var filter = admin.filter;
filter.call(admin, req, res, next); // just call
filter.call(admin, [req, res, next]); // good when you are using arguments
server.on('connect', admin.filter.bind(admin)); //if you need it as callback
setTimeout(admin.filter.bind(admin, req, res, next)); // if you know
// that one, who will call calback will not pass arguments itself.
```